# default_attrs.update(attrs) ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, django

I got this error when I wrote the new class, before that everything was working fine I read different links with the same error but I got no clue how to fix it
from django import forms

```
from .models import Topic, Entry

class  TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class  EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': 'Entry:'}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little python app with an Entry model and the form class just like you did

[image: forms.py] and the form rendered properly [image: form in browser]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but misteriously the problem was fixed alone, so thank you whatever happened lol